# How can I add this feature to my bat chatbot?

Tags: batch-file, chat, chatbot

This is my chatbot. I would like to add that if the input is something different than "yes" and "no" then it should echo "Wrong answer".

```
@ECHO OFF
title Bane
:CHAT
SET /P input=Oh You think darkness is your ally? (yes or no) Your message:

IF %input%==yes ECHO That's were you're wrong!
IF %input%==no ECHO Admirable, but mistaken.
GOTO CHAT
:END
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
title Bane
:CHAT
SET /P "input=Oh You think darkness is your ally? (yes or no) Your message: "
IF /i "%input%"=="yes" ECHO That's were you're wrong! & goto :end
IF /i "%input%"=="no" ECHO Admirable, but mistaken. & goto :end
echo wrong answer & goto :chat

:END
PAUSE
```

you might be interested in the `choice` command, which has it's own input verification:

```
@ECHO OFF
title Bane
:CHAT
choice /C YN /M "Oh You think darkness is your ally? Your message: "
if errorlevel 2 ECHO That's were you're wrong! & goto :end
if errorlevel 1 ECHO Admirable, but mistaken. & goto :end
echo wrong answer ; this line is never reached

:END
PAUSE
```

In the second code example I removed `(yes or no)`, as `choice` already prints out all valid choices. But of course you can keep it and supress default choices wihth `/n` (thanks, Compo, valid argument):

```
`choice /C YN /N /M "Oh You think darkness is your ally? (yes or no) Your message: "`
```

Comment: @AlfredWhite, if deciding to use the `Choice` command, _(recommended)_, then note that the default option is `/C YN` and therefore it is not necessary to add it in this case.

Comment: @compo for me, it's `JN` - depends on language.

Comment: I'm aware of language differences Stephan, my comment however was aimed at the person with the English name, who wrote their script and question in English. Now you've mentioned the language difference though, it would be even more important to leave the `/C YN` out in this case.

Comment: so a person with an Englisch Nickname needs to use an English Windows?

Comment: In your answer @Stephan, why use `yes or no`, you didn't use `/N` so the `[YN]` option will be provided to the end user, _(adding `yes or no` only confuses)_.